# How to highlight/copy multiple text elements in Adobe Acrobat PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I've been having trouble finding a solution to this problem. I'm adding scripting to a PDF form for my job, and my goal is to be able to highlight all 3 rows to allow for easy copying, but also keep the work description as the prepare form text elements so I'm able to interact with it via JavaScript.

The issues I've encountered are that if it's multiple text elements, then I've been unable to find a way to highlight the text in all 3 to allow for copying. Or another issue being that the multi-line text box seems to be much larger than where the text will appear, thus moving into other text lines of the form.

[Here is how the area looks in preview mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUpi.png)

[Here is how it looks in edit mode (Prepare Form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbeoe.png)

The only features I want for sure is to be able to copy the entire work description easily, and to keep the work description as an element that JavaScript can interact with.